# Why does my paintComponent method paint over my JButton? How can I make a JPanel have both a JButton and graphics on it?

Tags: java, swing

I am using two JPanels with a cardLayout, both being added onto a contentPane. There is one JButton on each of the panels that switch to the other panel but on my gridPanel, which has graphics on it, they seem to cover the JButton and although it still works when you click where it's position is, it is invisible. How do I get a JPanel that has both graphics on it and a JButton? Thank you so much for all of your help

Main Class:

```
public class ProjectileGame extends JPanel
{   
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyGame");
    private static JPanel panelContent = new JPanel();
    MenuPanel menuPanel = new MenuPanel();
    GridPanel gridPanel = new GridPanel();
    Ball ball = new Ball();

    static CardLayout card = new CardLayout(); 

    public ProjectileGame()
    {   
        frame.setTitle("ProjectileGame");
        frame.add(panelContent);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(900, 700);

        panelContent.setLayout(card);
        panelContent.add(menuPanel, "1");
        panelContent.add(gridPanel, "2");

        card.show(panelContent, "1");   //First JPanel to be shown is that of the main menu.

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }     

    public static void menuButtonPressed()
    {
        card.show(panelContent, "2");
    }

    public static void gridButtonPressed()
    {
        card.show(panelContent, "1");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new ProjectileGame();
    }
}
```

gridPanel Class:

```
public class GridPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private static final Graphics2D g2 = null;
    Ball ball = new Ball();
    JButton backToTheMenu = new JButton("To the Menu");
    Timer timer = new Timer(14, this);

    public GridPanel()
    {
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 710));
        add(ball);
        add(backToTheMenu);

        backToTheMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {       
                ProjectileGame.gridButtonPressed();
            }
        });
    } 

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d1 = (Graphics2D)g;

        ball.paintComponent(g2d1);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0,  649,  30,  33);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.drawLine(0, (20+(30*i)),  900,  (20+(30*i)));
            g.drawLine((30+(30*i)), 0, (30+(30*i)), 1000);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(0, 650, 900, 650);
        g.drawLine(30, 0, 30, 1000);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d1.drawString("X Displacement (metres)", 400, 667);
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.setToRotation(Math.PI / -1.97);
        g2d1.setTransform(at);
        g2d1.drawString("Y Displacement (metres)", -380, 8);    

    }                 

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        ball.ballPhysics();
        repaint();
        timer.restart();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "Ball"? If it is a Swing component, you should not be directly calling its paintComponent method. Also please post a valid [mcve].

Comment: Ball is my object that I created. How would I now post a minimal, complete and verifiable example?

Comment: `How do I get a JPanel that has both graphics on it and a JButton?` - well typically you wouldn't. I'm guessing you want to have a "Ball" object moving around the screen. So you would generally use a panel to do the animation of the Ball. If ball is a Swing component then you would use a null layout on the panel and then use the `setLocation()` method to move the ball. So you would then have a parent panel the probably used a BorderLayout. You might add the JButton to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START and the animation panel to the BorderLayout.CENTER.

Comment: Regarding the `MCVE`, your question is about a panel with graphics and a components. So all you need is a JFrame and a panel.. You then add a button to the panel and override the paintComponent() method and simply draw a String on the panel. Now you have a panel with graphics and a button. So the whole `MCVE` will be about 20 lines of code.

Comment: Regarding the MCVE, I see, thanks. In reply to camickr, but do you know how I could do it so that each panel has its own JButton? What if I didn't want to have one main screen with permanent buttons whilst the panel below the buttons keeps changing?

Comment: Remove `ball.paintComponent` from your GridPanel class.  The paintComponent method should not be painting children.  Swing already takes care of that elsewhere.

Comment: `how I could do it so that each panel has its own JButton?` - I already told you how to do that. You have a main panel with a CardLayout. Then you have two child panels. The child panel contains the button and the panel with the custom painting.

Comment: In reply to VGR (btw thanks for the help), when I take that out, my ball isn't painted anymore. In reply to camickr, (btw thanks for all of the help), "The child panel contains the button and the panel with the custom painting". So one of the child panels also contains two more panels, one with button and one with painting? At the moment I have 2 child panels, one with no painting and a visible button and one with painting, with no visible button. Im sorry I'm just a beginner so I don't really understand

Comment: `Im sorry I'm just a beginner so I don't really understand` - What don't you understand?  I already told you how to use a JPanel with a BorderLayout and add two components to it. Again you are thinking about your application and not thinking about the simple concept of a panel with two components. Once you know how to create a panel with two components added to it, that panel than then become one of your child components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add transforms and rotations etc. to the `Graphics` object passed to the `paintComponent()` method. This `Graphics` object is passed to all other components when they are painted.

Instead you should be creating a temporary `Graphics` object to do the painting:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();

    //  do custom painting

    g2d.dispose();
}
```

Now you need to be able to add multiple components to a panel. Note that you can always add another panel to a panel so you can have unlimited nested levels of panels. So you can easily create two "cards" for you CardLayout that each have a different number of components added to them.

The basics is something like:

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("Back to Card2") 
JPanel gridPanel = new GridPanel();
JPanel card1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
card1.add(button1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
card1.add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JButton button2 = new JButton("Back to Card1");
JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
card2.add(button2);

JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel();
cardPanel.setLayout( new CardLayout(...) );
cardPanel.add(card1, ...);
cardPanel.add(card2, ...);

frame.add(cardPanel);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try implementing this. Thanks for the help